# duplicating all activity instead of [check boxes and text only] (To do list android app)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I'm trying to make to-do list app. the design here "https://i.ibb.co/cXnQ9dP/Capture.png"

I got box and text code from "https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html" proj (15.1. Interaction between the model and Listview) but I put the XML code into my existing XML activity [not in a new activity] and changed activity name in super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list); and view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null); to my main activity name

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mando.todolist.new_list">
.............background and buttons code here............
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/plus"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="205dp"
        android:id="@+id/repeat_layout"
        >



        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px" >
        </CheckBox>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="50px"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/check"
            >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_new_list, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_new_list.,null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

```
public class new_list extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
                getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
    }

    private Model get(String s) {
        return new Model(s);
    }
}
```

The output is All activity has been duplicated [including background and buttons] instead duplicating checkbox with text only in the same activity

Comment: I've asked later but no one answered me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813883/duplicating-all-activity-instead-of-check-boxes-and-text-only-to-do-list-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [duplicating all activity instead of \[check boxes and text only\] To do list app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813883/duplicating-all-activity-instead-of-check-boxes-and-text-only-to-do-list-app)

Answer (score 0):

Move your background and buttons to the xml file where you put your ListView
it should look like this, because the item xml you are using where your CheckBox exists is the one used for the ListView, if you but the button it will duplicated too

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- background and buttons code here -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```